# Advice for Java based pipeline structure

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, httprequest

I really need a good advice for the following scenario. Actually it is simple structure [image: Java Pipeline]

As you can see in schema there are requests which will be handled by Java and some information in this request will be put in Amazon DynamoDb. There might be really thousands of requests per second and it should handle heavy requests.

I have basic structure in my mind

1. Use Spring or Lift framework to handle the request
2. Put item in a kind of pipeline ( I need your strong advice here for pipeline library, is apache pipeline still active? )
3. Put items to dynamodb with multi-thread running jobs.

As you can see this is really simple stuff. What would be the best way to implement this structure? I'm open for all kind of suggestions about the structure, library and methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Apache Camel? It even comes with a [DynamoDB component](http://camel.apache.org/aws-ddb.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your execution environment, you can use a Workmanager to handle the multi-thread part.  Actually it is the recommended way to multi-thread in JEE environments:

http://danielveselka.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/schedule-jobs-with-workmanager.html

http://aleung.github.io/blog/2012/08/10/understanding-weblogic-workmanager/

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fpublic_html%2Fapi%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fasynchbeans%2FWorkManager.html

However I'm afraid it's dependent on the implementation your environment gives you, and in some cases it even does not exist :(